# Ordering Modules that both use sales_order_place_after observer

Tags: magento-1.7, module, event-observer

I'm writing two custom modules that act independently on the `sales_order_place_after` event observer and modify order state and status. One module (Module A) will act on every order and update the state, status (pending dispatch) and create a shipment, and the other module (Module B) will only apply an action if some criteria is present (a fraud check) and mark the order back to another status (suspected fraud).

Currently it appears that they are firing in the order Module B then Module A when it needs to be the other way around. I get the impression this is what's occurring because the order history of an order that fulfils the criteria for ModuleB an order will go from `pending->suspected_fraud->pending_dispatch` when it should be going from `pending->pending_dispatch->suspected_fraud`

Is it possible to make Module A fire first and then Module B to fire second without combing the modules into 1?

Comment: in your Namespace_ModuleB.xml in app/etc/modules, add this line: `<depends><Namespace_ModuleA/></depends>`, after `<codePool>local</codePool>` line. Didn't check this, but anyway give it a try.

Comment: It worked! I thought of this but dismissed it but it absolutely worked. If you put this as an answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: all right, glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Namespace_ModuleB.xml in app/etc/modules, add this line:

```
<depends><Namespace_ModuleA/></depends>
```

after `<codePool>local</codePool>` line.

So that Module A will be executed before Module B.